# XQuery tag always returning String for full path?

Tags: string, tags, xquery, concatenation

Need help with this.
I have the following cycle:

```
<deviceInformationList>

{
   for $entityCounter in 2 to fn:count($getDeviceResponse/return/timList/packetSessionInfoList)
   return
       let $nameSeq := ('',
                       'sessionActive',
                       'sessionLastIpAddress')
       let $typeSeq := ('',
                       'String',
                       'String')
       let $valueSeq := ('',
                       'packetSessionActive',
                       'ipv4Address')
       return
            <deviceInformationItem>
                 <itemName>{ fn:concat($nameSeq[$entityCounter], $entityCounter) }</itemName>
                 <itemType>{ $typeSeq[$entityCounter] }</itemType>
                 <itemValue>{ data( fn:concat('$return/timList[1]/apnList[1]/', $valueSeq[$entityCounter]) ) }</itemValue>
            </deviceInformationItem>
}

</deviceInformationList>
```

I need to set the content of the tag **itemValue** as a full path to be interpreted and return the value from that field. I haven't found a way, every function I use gets interpreted as a String.
Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but might help. I think `</deviceInformationList>` at the top should be `<deviceInformationList>` to indicate an opening tag; you have to closing tags

Comment: The `data()` function does not evaluate the args passed to it like that (see http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-operators/#func-data). Depending on what processor you're using, there might be an eval extension function. Otherwise you'll have to approach the problem differently.

Comment: Please have a look at [how to provide an SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org) and provide example input to work with, and also current and expected output.

Comment: Thanks Chris. But that was a mistype, corrected.
Daniel, I'm using Oracle OSB, any leads on how to do it? Or other solution rather than this one?